# Why am I screaming?

Tags: word, computer-puzzle, steganography

Simply find what is hidden in this picture.

[image: The Scream]

Comment: Is it something like [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5555/5373)?

Comment: Nope. No Fourier transforms involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> **ICE CREAM**.  The reference is ["I Scream, You Scream, We All Scream for Ice Cream"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Cream_%28I_Scream,_You_Scream,_We_All_Scream_for_Ice_Cream%29)
>
> The hidden text is revealed in the bit 0 plane by using the [Stegsolve](http://www.caesum.com/handbook/stego.htm) program
>
>  [image: IceCream]
> **I** - my first is in ice but not in cream
> **C** - the element Carbon can be hard and precious in a diamond
> **E** - 2.71828 is the number $e$
> **CREAM** - has already been said

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the bit 0 plane?

Comment: I new I should have made it harder. Well done. Didn't know about Stegsolve.

Comment: @Quark - I added a link for looking at the individual RGB bits.

Comment: @Len Thanks for the link, I'm surprised how easy this is to use. I'll be using Stegsolve for years to come =)