# Oh no! A hacker has taken control of my computer!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

It seems that some guy called *Magick* has taken over my computer. Well, there does not seem to be any harmful stuff done at least, but this picture keeps appearing on my screen.

[image]

"HACKED by Magick"? What the ...? This guy thinks he is a magician with computers?

I also get a popup box asking for a password in order to get rid of all that, but I have no idea where to get that password. You guys seem to be pretty good at solving puzzles in here. Could you help me, please?

EDIT:
The hacker, seeing I'm not advancing so well, gave me a hint:

> Several steps: magical *decipher*, remove center, line out, subtract, play.

Comment: Kind of reminds me of [this one](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/hidden-in-plain-sight-by-what-method-do-these-images-hide-a-prime-number/)

Comment: @Quark, What did you try exactly ?

Comment: After your comment, I realized I probably had the right idea. Turns out my "ensure new line at end of file" setting in sublime was messing it up. On to part two.

Comment: I'm stuck on the second part, tried multiple audio extractors with no luck. Needs more hints to be less guess-and-check. If you want to allow partial answers I can post the first part.

Comment: @Quark, It's up to you to give your partial answer, but that will not count as a full answer of course !

Comment: @Quark can you post the partial answer..maybe we can work on this as a community?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Partial Answer:

> `Magick` gives the hint that [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (a popular image manipulation software suite) is used.  You need to create a file with the password in it, then use ImageMagick's `-decipher` option.  In this case the password is `HACKED`.  On Linux the commands for this are:
>
> ```
> echo -n HACKED > pass
> convert 6SIFG.png -decipher pass decoded.png
> ```
>
> The `-n` option is necessary to prevent `echo` from adding a trailing newline to the end of the file.

After all that, you get the following deciphered image:

> [image]

Following is 2012rcampion's work:

> If you treat the image data as 16-bit audio samples and play them at 44100Hz you get [a computer-generated voice saying "cipher."](https://youtu.be/4hnCDWyHBNg) Using Mathematica: `ListPlay[Flatten@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikSJG.png", "Data"], SampleRate -> 44100]`

According to the OP's comment, the password is:

> cipher

Comment: If you treat the image data as 16-bit audio samples and play them at 44100Hz you get a robovoice saying "cipher."  (For my future reference: `ListPlay[Flatten@Import["http://i.stack.imgur.com/ikSJG.png", "Data"],
  SampleRate -> 44100]`)

Comment: ...the challenge now is *which* cipher, and which of the unused parts of the image is the ciphertext?  My guess is that that's what "line out, subtract" and the 6000 are referring to.

Comment: Not really @Campion, the 6000 is for having a zeroed background from unsigned to signed int. The word you found is intended to be the password. Sorry the story didn't go further!