# Number 88 from the digits 2, 0, 1 and 7?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Can you use the digits 2, 0, 1 and 7 each only **once** to create the number 88?

Comment: What are the allowed operations? Just +, -, / and * or can we use powers, factorials, etc?

Comment: I got 42 with 7! mod 102. :S

Comment: @darkdemise if all you want it to get close, just do 7X12 or 170 / 2. no need to work so hard XD

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's so special about 88?

Comment: Are other digits allowed?

Comment: @Pharap Exactly what I was thinking. 2*0*1*7+88 uses each of the digits 2, 0, 1 and 7 only once. I'm guessing no. :)

Comment: 0-2 & 7 +1 assuming rot 8 and allowing concatenation

Comment: Please specify the rules.

Comment: I've brute-forced this problem with addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, exponentiation, negation, and factorial and not found any result for 88 (or a bunch of other positive integers below 100, for that matter). On to square roots and modulo operations...

Comment: [In the spirit of hexomino's and Andrew's answers...](http://i.imgur.com/LSYQ02p.png) ;)

Comment: the number 88 is nazi symbology, given that H is the eighth letter of the alphabet, and a person with the initials HH being very important to neo-nazis.... I would dare to say OP is absolutely trolling this SE.

Comment: @cantido, [or not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future).  That seemed like kind of a stretch.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

What about this

> $\left(\frac{0!}{.\overline1}\right)^2 + 7 = 88$

where

> $.\overline1 = 0.1111\ldots$

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: Why is this accepted?

Comment: @the why shouldn't it be?

Comment: @Nick well, the OP never actually told us what they were after. I'm just wondering why the OP considered this a better answer than all the others.

Comment: @theonlygusti, then ask OP and not the answerer. :P  $\quad$

Comment: @theonlygusti My guess is because it appears to be the first answer and it  meets the challenge.

Comment: This one also seems to add the least amount of handwavium to get to the solution.

Comment: @tfitzger, Handwavium... I like that element!

Answer (score 53):

No rules?

[image]

Looks like 88 to me if I squint.

Comment: [Looks right to me](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/hidden-in-plain-sight-by-what-method-do-these-images-hide-a-prime-number/5566#5566)

Answer (score 33):

Because modern math is done with computers, here's some Python:

```
>>> int(str(0 + 1 + 7) * 2)
88
```

Comment: I disagree that modern maths is done with computers. See the [IMO](https://www.imo-official.org/) and other related mathematics competitions.

Comment: Similarly in C#: `new string((1 + 7).ToString()[0], 2)`

Comment: @boboquack Long-distance running is one of the best known competitions in the Olympics; still, modern commuters drive.

Comment: If you're going to do something like this, why not use BF? You just put `2017` in the front, and then put the BF code after.

Comment: I'm not sure is string manipulation is a mathematical operation

Comment: @user902383 point out where in the op mathematical operations are mentioned, let alone required

Comment: Tag [tag:mathematics] was [added afterwards by another poster](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/48740/revisions)

Answer (score 26):

For that matter:

> In base 86: $12 + 0*7$

Comment: This *does* answer the question. In base 86 the numerals 12 = 88 in base 10. Adding the 0*7 in just a cheeky way of disposing of two useless numbers. How do I create 88 from 1, 2, 0 and 7? Change the base!

Comment: In base 86, the number OP asked for doesn't exist. So no, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Josh Sure it does. 88 base 10 = 12 base 86, which Bob used. Or, the other way around 88 base 86 = 696 base 10.

Comment: Here is a good example of where the question asked needs to have proper constraints.  I see another answer which involved changing the base.  And to take the unconstrained problem one step further, someone even suggested that superimposing 1 over 2, and 7 over zero looks like 88.  In my own defense, no one would argue that 0xf is 15.  I don't see how saying "12 base 86 is 88" is any different.

Comment: @BobDeMattia Really?  Because the **only** information I can find on 0xf is that it's [the number 15](http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/15/en).

Comment: This answer uses 8 and 6...

Comment: @JMac  That's what I said!

Answer (score 21):

If floor were allowed, then this works:

> $\left\lfloor\sqrt{10!!}\right\rfloor + 27  $

because

> $10!!$ is $10\cdot 8\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2 = 3840 $
>  $\sqrt{3840} = 61.9677335393\cdots.$

Answer (score 12):

The only *digits* used here are **2,0,1,7** to reach **88**:

> $(\textbf{10}+(i\times i))^\bf2\rm+\bf7 = 88$

Comment: With this you could literally make any number though. Start at some number and add any amount of i^4 as required.

Answer (score 11):

We can do it without the $0$...

> $S=\{1,2,7\}$
>
>  $(\sum{S}-|S|)\times\prod{S}-\sum{S}$
>
>  (using the sum, $\sum$, cardinality, $||$, and product,$\prod$, of the set $S$.)
>
>  Evaluated:
>  $=(10-3)\times 14-10$
>  $=7\times 14-10$
>  $=98-10$
>  $=88$

So, obviously we could just add zero afterwards.

Mind you, I suppose that we could also do it with just one of the numbers in that case too.

> $S = \{x\}$
>
>  $(|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|+|S|)\times(|S|+|S|)\times(|S|+|S|)\times(|S|+|S|)$
>  $=(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)\times(1+1)\times(1+1)\times(1+1)$
>  $=11\times2 \times2 \times2$
>  $=88$

...so
For $x = $...$7$, $2$, or $1$ just multiply the rest together and add them on.
For $x=0$ one can add $(7\times 2)\pmod{1}=0$, or $(7+1)\pmod{2}=0$.

---

The only question is: Does doing what I have done here count as using the given numbers more than once?

---

Here is an alternative, sneaky way...

> Subtract the **one** from the **seven**, turn the resulting six upside-down, append the **zero**, then subtract the **two**.
>
>  $7-1=6$
>  $\text{turn}(6)=9$
>  $\text{append}(9,0)=90$
>  $90-2=88$

Comment: Just add a $+0$ onto the end.

Comment: I'm a big fan of the sneaky way.

Comment: Why not x = 2 * 0 * 7 + 1, and then x + x + x + ... + x = 88?  Seems like once you're allowed to define variables, the challenge is lost.

Comment: if you are allowed to use sets you don't need any digits.

Comment: define sneakyfunc(2,0,1,7) = 88.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Agreed - it's borderline - hence why I wrote "Does doing what I have done here count as using the given numbers more than once?" (the question does say "digits". The reason I gave the first answer is that using a set is not *exactly* the same as using a variable as I am using its properties rather than as a placeholder to actually reuse the digits themselves.

Comment: @NeilW wow, now that *is* sneaky.

Comment: @Jasen, Yes I suppose so! (you mean like $A=\{\}$, $B=\{A\}$, $|B|=1$?)

Comment: yeah,  |{{}}|=1 so 88= (|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|)(|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|+|{{}}|)

Answer (score 7):

If ceiling or nearest integer function is allowed,

> $\lceil{\tan^{-1}(27+0!)}\rceil = 88^{\circ}$

Comment: That's the cleverest use of the 1, I think... to turn tan into arctan.

Answer (score 5):

- Use **"2"** and **"0"** as digital numbers to combine them to form **"8"**
- Add **"1"** and **"7"** mathematically and the result is **"8"**

So **"88"**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a perl one-liner you could write:

> `perl -le 'for ($_=-1-2,$i = 0; $i<7; $i++) {$_+= $i*$i }; print'`

or **without a zero**:

> `perl -le 'print ((7+1)x2)'`

or **without a zero OR a two** in the bash shell:

> `x=$((7+1)) && echo $x$x`

or **without a zero, one, or two** in bash:

> `false || x=$((7+$?)) && echo $x$x`

or **without any numbers at all**:

> `false || x=$(($?+$?+$?+$?+$?+$?+$?+$?)) && echo $x$x`

Comment: The puzzle is tagged [mathematics], not [programming].

Comment: @Glorfindel the puzzle is also tagged [calculation-puzzle]. my answer involves both mathematics and calculations.

Comment: You could build any number you want. this way. No fair! :D

Comment: ...or in English `eighty-eight`.

Answer (score 2):

If we use base 36

> We now have access to the digits 2, 0, 1, A, N, D, 7.
>  So:
>  $= (N \times D) - 7 + \left(\frac{A}{2}\right) - 1 + 0$
>  $= 8B - 7 + 5 - 1 + 0$
>  $= 8B - 3$
>  $= 88$ 
>
>  Using base 10 math gives us 2, 0, 1, 10, 13, 23, 7
>  $= (23 \times 13) - 7 + \left(\frac{10}{2}\right) - 1 + 0$
>  $= 299 - 7 + 5 - 1 + 0$
>  $= 299 - 3$
>  $= 296$
>  296 is 88 in base 36

Comment: But that's not what the question is asking for.

Comment: The question says using those four digits once only. Your answer is the equivalent of saying "well, if I also use these other digits, I can get the answer!" which is completely besides the point.

Comment: Using the digits "2 0 1 and 7", if `extract_digits=lambda x:set(" ".join(x).split())`. However, the usual definition is `extract_digits=lambda x:set(parse_english(x))`.

Comment: Why are we allowed to use $D$?  I can agree with using $A$ in base 36 as a creative way of using $1$ and $0$, especially since the question never specified base 10, but why is $D_{36} = 13_{10}$ ok?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my first answer after about 5 minutes of brute-force checks!

> $\lceil\log{\sqrt{102!}}\rceil+7=88$

where log means logarithm in base 10.

By the way, as a wild guess, I think that 88 is very likely to be the OP's birth year.

Comment: Or, perhaps, age. You can never tell, unless you're a data miner or have access to said data miner's data.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 This could have been another puzzle. And we can never be sure about a puzzle's solution until the puzzle owner reveals the answer...

Comment: It's the visual representation of a 7-bar numerical display. Interpreting it as such gives `1111111 1111111`. ASCII has seven bits; interpreting this number as ASCII gives `DEL` `DEL`. The OP wants to delete all puzzles.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Add some evil laughs to the background

Comment: I thought $88$ was a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future).

Answer (score 1):

> $0!-(.7-.1)\times.2$
>
>  $= 1 - (0.6)(0.2)$
>
>  $= 1 - 0.12 = 0.88$
>
>  remove the decimal point to get $088=88$.

Answer (score 1):

> In base 9:
>
>  $$88 = 102 - \lceil\sqrt 7\rceil$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another one.

$$\lceil{\sqrt{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\right)!} \times \left( 2 + 0! + 1\right)!}\rceil}$$

Breaking it down:

$$7! = 5040$$
$$\sqrt{7!} = \sqrt{5040} = 70.992957$$
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}} = \sqrt{70.992957} = 8.42573$$
$$\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\right)! = 8.42573! = 101358.44566$$
$$\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\right)!} = \sqrt{101358.44566} = 318.368411$$
$$ \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\right)!} \times \left(2 + 0! + 1\right)! = 318.368411 \times 24 = 7640.84$$
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\right)!} \times \left(2 + 0! + 1\right)!} = \sqrt{7640.84} =  87.412$$

$$\lceil{\sqrt{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{7!}}\right)!} \times \left( 2 + 0! + 1\right)!}\rceil} = \lceil{ 87.412 \rceil} = 88$$

Answer (score 1):

Another use of mathematical functions and flooring...

> $\lfloor\ln\Gamma(\frac{7\times10}{2})\rfloor$
>
>  $=\lfloor\ln\Gamma(35)\rfloor$
>
>  $=\lfloor88.58082754219768\rfloor$
>
>  $=88$
>
>  Reference: [$\ln\Gamma(x)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html)

Answer (score 0):

If subfactorial is allowed:

> $!(7-2)\times(1+0!)=44\times2=88$