# Combine 3, 3, 5 & 7 to get 24

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Using operators plus, minus, multiplied by and divide by, and as many brackets as you want, can you do a formula which uses 3, 3, 5 and 7 to make 24?

Each number must be used and can only be used once (so there will be two 3's).

So, for example, (3x7)+3 makes 24, but this isn't valid because the 5 wasn't used.

I don't know if this is possible, btw! It's in a game I'm playing.

Comment: Well, I noticed that $${\large 57-33=24}.$$ Does this break any rules?

Comment: It's called [24 game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24_Game) for anyone wondering.

Comment: @user477343 Accepted comment.

Comment: Challenge 24. Nostalgia.

Comment: @user477343 Definitely a good answer https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5555/hidden-in-plain-sight-by-what-method-do-these-images-hide-a-prime-number/5566#5566

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, I tried to solve it the hard way (using double fractions) but actually it's quite easy.

> (3 * 5 - 7) * 3 = (15 - 7) * 3 = 8 * 3 = 24

Comment: Indeed, by brute-force search, this is the only formula up to commutative transformation.

Answer (score 16):

Heh, how about:

```
(3 XOR 5) x (3 XOR 7)
```

... yes, yes, I know XOR's not allowed.  Poor XOR.  Nobody ever invites him.

Comment: Nice twist in this answer!

Comment: Could someone please explain this answer? I know XOR as a logic gate but I don't understand how can it be used here?

Comment: @defectedWBC - XOR on numbers treats each bit independently.  3 XOR 5 is:  0011 XOR 0101, which is 0110, or 6.  Likewise, 3 XOR 7 is: 0011 XOR 0111 = 0100, or 4.  If you're on a windows machine, you can go into Calculator and set it to Programmer mode, and perform XOR's as well.

Answer (score 7):

what about this one?

> using factorials of 3
>  $7+5+3!+3! = 24$

Comment: Nice but the question lists specific operators. The factorial is not one of them. I solved one of these using binomials once. Although this does not use new operators it does rely on the placement of the numbers and should not be accepted.

Answer (score 7):

We can use as many brackets as we want, and [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(mathematics)#Floor/ceiling_functions_and_fractional_part)

> Square brackets, as in  [π] = 3, are sometimes used to denote the floor function, which rounds a real number down to the next integer.

So I will use square brackets `[]` to denote the floor function.

> $$([5 \div 3]+7) \times 3 = (1+7) \times 3 = 8 \times 3 = 24$$

If we massage the rules a little more, and can put numbers in different positions, we can use [Falling Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket_(mathematics)#Falling_and_rising_factorial) notation, where

$$(x)_n = x(x-1)(x-2)\ \cdot \cdot \cdot (x-n+1) = \frac{x!}{(x-n)!}$$

> $$[(5)_3 \div 7] \times 3 = \big[\frac{5!}{(5-3)!} \div 7 \big] \times 3 = [60 \div 7] \times 3 = 8 \times 3 = 24$$

Unfortunately, there is no way to use [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) to get the given input to 24.

Comment: argh, it was going so well.

Answer (score 5):

When we

> combine 3 and 3 it makes 33

and when we

> combine 5 and 7 it makes 57

then

> subtract 57-33

it will give the answer 24

Answer (score 4):

How about:

> 3 + 3 + 5 + 7 **+ 6** = 24

Explanation:

> Each number must be used and can only be used once, **but the rules don't say *other* numbers cannot be used**!

Comment: Hmm, I guess i did miss an "only" there.

Answer (score 2):

I also thought about :

> $3 * (7 - 5) ^ 3$

Breaks the rule but hey

Answer (score -3):

please check it

> $(3*3*5)-(7*3) = 45-21 = 24$

Comment: It's got an extra 3, so it's breaking the rules.

Answer (score -3):

Seems pretty straight forward, sorry I don't know how to hide it:

> (5x7) - (3x3) = 35 - 9 = 24

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong: 35 - 9 = 26, not 24.

Comment: Sure, engineer, I can do math!  Out of practice it seems.

Answer (score -3):

check it
3!+3!+5+7
=6+6+12
=24

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This uses an operator (!) which is not allowed according to the rules in the question.